# Lazy reinit a list to modifiable after declaring with Collections.emptyList()

Tags: java, reference, new-operator

Want to declare a list as  `List<String> info = Collections.emptyList()`
but when user calls add(String msg) then re-init to a modifiable list.

Is this the correct way:

```
private List<String> info = Collections.emptyList();
public void addInfo(String s){
        final List<String> e = Collections.emptyList();
        if(info == e){
            info = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        info.add(s);
    }
```

Or

`if(info.equals(e)){`

If I have 3 of these can I have this common code :

```
public void addInfo(String s) {
        info = addTo(s, info);
    }
    public void addWarn(String s) {
        warn = addTo(s, warn);
    }

    public void addErr(String s) {
        errs = addTo(s, errs);
    }

    private List<String> addTo(String s, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull List<String> t){
        final List<String> e = Collections.emptyList();
        if(t.equals(e)){
            t = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        t.add(s);
        return t;
    }
```

I guess the following wont work due to the new list being created?

```
private void addTo(String s, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull List<String> t){
    final List<String> e = Collections.emptyList();
    if(t.equals(e)){
        t = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    t.add(s); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.equals` is the only correct solution -- but equivalent to the much simpler `info.isEmpty()`.

Comment: thank you, this is the easiest way. Also I guess for the 2nd question,  need to return the ref if i make a new object right? 
`if(t.isEmpty()){
    t = new ArrayList<>(); 
} 
return t;` ?

Comment: @sprinter, as written, you definitely do need to return the reference.  The OP's last code sample is a no-op if the collection was initially empty.

Answer (score 2):

Note that even if `Collections.emptyList()` always returns the one instance held in `Collections.EMPTY_LIST`, a reference comparison does not detect when a caller used JDK 9+ `List.of()` to initialize the field. On the other hand, being non-empty does not guaranty mutability either.

The entire logic is suitable only for a `private` method were all callers and their usage are known.

But you should consider the alternative of dropping these special cases altogether. Since Java 8, the default constructor `new ArrayList<>()` will not create a backing array. It is deferred until the first addition of an element.

So you can initialize all fields with a plain `new ArrayList<>()` and implement the `addInfo`, `addWarn`, and `addErr` with a plain `add` call, getting rid of the `addTo` method, the conditionals, and the repeated assignments. Even declaring the fields `final` is possible. While still not requiring a significant amount of memory for the unused lists.

Comment: Good to know, will research and get back

Answer (score 1):

Considering your code:

```
    final List<String> e = Collections.emptyList();
    if(info == e){
        info = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    info.add(s);
```

I don't believe there's any guarantee in the Java API that the same reference will always be returned from `emptyList()` (the javadoc states "Implementations of this method need not create a separate List object for each call").

Given you may modify the list it'd make more sense to initialise with `new ArrayList<>()` rather than `emptyList()`. Really doesn't make much sense to use an unmodifiable list that you may want to modify.

However if you really need to use `emptyList()` for some reason, then perhaps:

```
if (info.isEmpty())
    info = new ArrayList<>();
```

Given you are about to add an item to it this test will only pass once anyway.

Comment: Using empty but another way would be to  `final static List<String> EMPTY_LIST = Collections.emptyList();   List<String> info = EMPTY_LIST;` then I think in the func can use info == EMPTY_LIST though not 'usual' Java code, would work. I like this as we use this object to return info from an API. In 98% cases the lists are empty. but in the 2% when we have warnings, errors... need to accommodate them. saving memory like this makes for stretching nodes to handle more txns. sometimes are nodes get 3x load and go from 10 transactions a second to 30 (each node), this helps lower total nodes needed